# Comparing list length

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of lists, let's say:

```
import Data.List

xs = [[1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3]]
```

I want to get the inner list with the most items, in this case `[1,2,3]`.

I'm trying to use the `maximumBy` function from the `Data.List` library:

```
maximumBy (compare `on` length) xs
```

but I get the following error: `not in scope 'on'`

Can anyone tell me what is wrong, or if you have a better way to get the list?

Comment: As an exercise, try not to use `on`, instead writing the argument to `maximumBy` by hand:  `maximumBy (\x y -> ...) xs`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`on` is defined in [Data.Function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v%3aon), so you need to import that.

Alternatively, you can use `comparing` from [Data.Ord](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ord.html#v%3acomparing):

```
maximumBy (comparing length) xs
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked... didnt know i needed another libary.  Haskell Noob here.

Comment: ya i will... need to wait 5 minutes!

Comment: @Special--k [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is great for figuring out which module a function needs to be imported from.

Answer (score 8):

While using `maximumBy` with `comparing length` or `` compare `on` length `` will do the job just fine for short lists, note that this is not a very efficient solution if the lists are long, since each time the algorithm compares two lists, it will re-calculate their lengths.

For example, if we have a very long first list, followed by many short lists,  using `maximumBy` will be very slow since the length of the first list will be re-calculated at each step.

```
> import Data.List
> import Data.Ord
> let xs = replicate 50000 'a' : replicate 50000 "b"
> maximumBy (comparing length) xs
<snip>
(16.09 secs, 98338680 bytes)
```

We can get a more efficient solution by caching the lengths of the lists:

```
> let longest xss = snd $ maximumBy (comparing fst) [(length xs, xs) | xs <- xss]
> longest xs
<snip>
(0.35 secs, 91547296 bytes)
```

Of course, this might not make a big difference if your lists are small, but it's worth taking note of.

Comment: Isn't there any other non-recalculating version of `maximumBy`? Btw, how do you get `ghci` to print run-time?

Comment: @Tarrasch: Not in any of the standard libraries, I think. Use `:set +s` to enable timing of each evaluation.

Comment: @Tarrasch: Apparently, [there was a proposal to add such functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2659), but it seems to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
maximumBy (comparing length)
```

or

```
maximumBy (on compare length)
```

or

```
maximumBy (compare `on` length)
```

Answer (score 4):

or you can make it a bit more explicit:

```
xs = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3]]
ordLen a b = compare (length a) (length b)
maximumBy ordLen xs
```

maybe it's easier to understand this way.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by hammar's solution, but with just one pass thru the list:

```
import Data.List

longest = snd . foldl' cmp (0,[]) where
   cmp maxPair@(maxLen, _) list = 
      let len = length list 
      in if len > maxLen then (len, list) else maxPair
```